# GSI capacity mode will be on-demand when primary Table has on-demand capacity mode?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index, dynamodb-gsi

**GSI capacity mode will be on-demand** when primary Table has on-demand capacity mode?

I am not able to find this information on the AWS documentation. Though what I am able to find is: RCU and WCU(provisioned capacity mode) should be same(or more) for GSI as otherwise it can backup the writes on the 'primary' Table, and thus throttling of requests.

What I found from the documentation is this:
Global secondary indexes inherit the read/write capacity mode from the base table
(copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

Can I assume GSI will **inherit** the capacity mode of table(thus its going to be on-demand for GSI, if its on-demand for the Table)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, a little experiment shows the following when I try adding a GSI to an On Demand table:

[image]

Comment: shoot, why I have never though of trying it in first place. Thank you for pointing out as well solving the puzzle for me.